# Why is mySQL Trigger not saving?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, triggers, sql-insert

I'm trying to create a trigger that stops insert if two inserts with same "St_Obr" were already made. It shows no errors, yet when I execute SQL script the trigger doesn't get saved. At least it's not shown when I execute SHOW TRIGGERS;

Code:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER ob_limit
BEFORE INSERT ON TUP.Lab FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT @a = COUNT(*)
    FROM TUP.Lab
    WHERE St_Obr = NEW.St_Obr;
    IF (@a > 2) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'MAX 2!';
    END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to *assign* the count to the variable, while your code *compares* it. This would require using a declared variable and selecting `into` it.

But I find that it is simpler to skip the variable and run the query directly in the `if` statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ob_limit
BEFORE INSERT ON Lab FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    
    IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Lab WHERE St_Obr = NEW.St_Obr) >= 2) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'MAX 2!';
    END IF;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Note that I change the inequality from `>` to `>=2`: the former allows three rows per `St_Obr`, while the latter permits 2 only (which is what you seem to want).

Here is a **[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qBtKc9aoZRsLDakcWrCGzJ/0)**; you can comment or uncomment the thrid `insert` to generate the error.

Comment: Thank you for your correction, but trigger is still not shown after executing it.

Comment: @GašperŠtepec: I just changed the answer, and added a DB Fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

In an `BEFORE` trigger the inserted row cannot be "seen" by the `SELECT count(*) ...` statement in the trigger. It is execute before the new row is inserted into the table. You can reduce the limit to `1` or use `>=` as GMB suggests. Or you can change the trigger to an `AFTER` trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ob_limit
               AFTER INSERT ON Lab
               FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF (SELECT count(*)
            FROM Lab
            WHERE st_obr = new.st_obr) > 2 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
           SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'MAX 2!';
  END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

(Note that the way you assigned the result to the variable was also erroneous. But there's no need for a variable, you can use the subquery directly in the comparison.)

Comment: Checked your solution, and it works as well. Thank you!